# Visual Studio node.js build settings

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, angular, visual-studio-2015, task-runner-explorer

I am trying to setup a development environment using Visual Studio for an Angular 2 typescript project, using a visual studio node.js project.

If I use the command line, everything works fine, my typescript is compiled, and my app runs like it should. However, using the visual studio build and run - it doesn't work.
My Issue is that I am using this [this](https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal) angular 2 control, and apperantly this project's tests won't transpile, and it create's build errors.

Is there a way to configure visual studio build settings for node.js projects? is there a way to suppress these errors? Can I actually set Visual Studio to run npm/ gulp scripts instead of MSBuild?

(I am aware of the task runner, but since it only has beforeBuild, AfterBuild, Clean and ProjectOpen binding, it doesn't seem like it will solve my problem.)